# Int64 not supporting pattern matching in C#

Tags: c#, pattern-matching

I stumbled upon this today. I have an Int64 variable, which cannot be cast to an int nor an int64 variable using type pattern matching in C#.

I.e.:

```
someValue is int: false
property.Value.GetType().ToString(): "System.Int64"
property.Value is System.Int64: false
```

I hope that someone can help clarify it for me, as it makes no sense for me right now. I can probably just do an int.tryParse() and solve this, but I would want to understand what failed and learn from it, even if I end up going another route.

Thanks!

**Edit/Update:**

So the code works both in Linqpad, Dotnetfiddle and in my compiled code, but it fails in the "Immediate Window" in Visual Studio 2019, where I can run code snippets.

See following image for what I mean (when I evaluate the expression in the Immediate Window - while code execution is at the breakpoint - it still says false, even if it has to be true to be within this if-condition):
[image]

I do not want to be the boy that cried wolf, especially if I am wrong, but could it be an Immediate Window bug, since it gives me an opposing result to what the If-statement in the code just evaluated to?

Comment: provide the actual code

Comment: From what you've shown us, i cannot [reproduce](https://sharplab.io/#v2:C4LgTgrgdgNAJiA1AHwAICYCMBYAUBgBjwwGYACAbzzJrI3UutuYBsB7KAczIEMyBeMpgIEA3E2Y1UmAJwAKPgEsAzmUVRgASnG5JtafJ4A6AOIBTYABUAngAczczdomSDCtaoCSGgGwAWZ11aAF88YKA===).

Comment: `property.Value is System.Int64` should return `true` if `Value.GetType().ToString()` is `System.Int64`, so there's probably something you are not showing (check https://dotnetfiddle.net/8ZUqsJ )

Comment: I will try to make a reproducible case, 15 min and it should be there. Thanks for responses so far!

Comment: Since you checked for an `int` in the first row, maybe you have missunderstood pattern matching. Pattern matching will _not_ perform any casts or conversions. If you match against a `struct`, it will unbox the value if required. If you match against a `class` it will check the type hirarchy to determine wheter the assignment is valid.

Comment: An int in c# is 32 bits so you can't cast a 64 bit number to 32.  You would need to AND the 64 bit number with 0xFFFFFFFF before casting to a 32 bit number.

Comment: @Pretasoc That was actually a mistake I made too, so thanks for also pointing it out! It seems to work in both Linqpad and dotnetfiddle, but not in Visual Studios "Immediate Window", where I can evaluate code on the fly. Will update initial question now to reflect this.